# Scala IDE for Eclipse : how to control local variable indentation

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, formatting, code-readability

I need to be able to control how my local variable are indented when declaring them :
let's say I write

```
val x           = 500
val SomeLongVar = "mybook"
```

when I press CTRL+SHIFT the idea changes the indentation to

```
val x = 500
val SomeLongVar = "mybook"
```

Any idea how can I change such setting?

EDIT:
One possible solution is to use the "format: OFF " option. 
First I did my own indention to the code then put // format: OFF before and // format: ON after.

```
// format: OFF
val x           = 500
val SomeLongVar = "mybook"

// format: ON
```

now when I press CTRL+SHIFT my local variable formatting will not be impacted.

Comment: As for version 3.0.1 of the Scala IDE, there is not any way to turn off or otherwise change the formatter's behavior with respect to vars & vals (Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Formatter).

Comment: thanks @richard-sitze you gave me a good hint.